# Why right click event not worked in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem, right-click

I want to delete my listbox item on right click. But, right click event not worked in my case.
Below is the code which I tried.

In constructor:

```
listBox1.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(listBox1_MouseRightClick);
```

Right Click:

```
private void listBox1_MouseRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListBoxItem)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToDelete = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)item.DataContext;

            MessageBoxResult Result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Confirmation", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

            if (Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                Globals._globalController.harvestManager.deleteHarvestEntry(entryToDelete);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Delete operation Terminated");
            }
        }
    }
```

In xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,131,0,59" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" SelectionMode="Single" MouseRightButtonDown="listBox1_MouseRightClick">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
           <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="listBox1_MouseRightClick"/>
       </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Please suggest, how should I use right click event so it could work?

Comment: Deleting a record on right-click seems like a poor design choice - right-click is almost universally accepted as a safe way to bring up a context menu.

Comment: I retracted my close vote and deleted the comment after reading your question more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code seems redundant and verbose. `MouseRightButtonDown` isn't working because there is already an event handling listbox item selection and the `ListBoxItem` datacontext is simply the `SelectedItem` of listBox1.

Get rid of overriding the style and just declare the listbox with the preview event. This will tunnel `MouseRightButtonDown` instead of bubble it.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
         Margin="0,131,0,59"
         SelectionMode="Single" 
         PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="listBox1_MouseRightClick" />
```

In the constructor, get rid of this

```
listBox1.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(listBox1_MouseRightClick);
```

Now in the event handler, `sender` is your listbox1 but if you're not tying this event to other listboxes, simply get the selectedItem from listbox1 and cast it to the appropriate object. Otherwise if you decide you want the functionality on multiple listboxes cast `sender` to `ListBox`

```
private void listBox1_MouseRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToDelete = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)listBox1.SelectedItem;
      if(entryToDelete != null)
      {
          //Do work
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting records on right click is not a good design and it leads users make more confuse the functionality. Still if you want to do something, then you can go for the **PreviewMouseRightButtonDown** event. Please see the below snippet

```
ListBox1.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBox1_MouseRightButtonDown);
```

Change your XAML as follows

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             Margin="0,131,0,59"
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
             SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                             Handler="ListBox1_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer and try the XAML which is working for me